# Trying to remove a slash from a URL in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Sorry for the simple question, promise I checked first.
OK, so I had an old site on `root`. It wasn't cpanel and was all flat html (old atwone server actually).
So, in html images are referenced in `/A/`
So, an image is at `/A/img.jpg`.

Now, I've archived this on another server, but in a subdomain: `old`. 
So, the structure is now `/old/A/img.jpg`

However, the references are the same, meaning the link is broken (images don't display).

When I edit this in Chrome and remove the fwd slash from `/A/image.jpg`, the image appears.
Moreover, if I add `/old/A/image.jpg`, it also works.

I take this to mean that wherever there's an instance of `/A/`, we need to rewrite to `A/`.
Or, we need to insert /old/.

The question is, how do I accomplish this in `.htaccess`?

I've tried a bunch of different methods, none seem to work.

I thought this might:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^A/?$ /old/A/$1 [NC,L]
```

Keeping in mind the first slash i.e. `^A/` is implied, i.e. is, `/A/`

Be gentle, I tried loads of methods first before posting. And yes, I'm a total htaccess rank novice and am slowly learning.

Thanks for any help! :)

EDIT FOR CLARITY

Working URL for image www.domain.com/old/A/img.jpg
Not working URL for image: www.domain.com/A/img.jpg <--- this is the URL from the old site/server. (It is not clear what rewrites there were, if any).

Comment: Not clear. What is working URL of image at present (not causing 404) and what rewrite you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rules as **very first rule** in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(A/.+)$ /old/$1 [NC,L,R=302]
```